# Dropping max value in list, keeping duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, max, min

I have a list of lists containing integers.
For example, one line would look like this:

```
my_list = [11,11,10]
```

I want to drop the max value, with the purpose of keeping the 2 smallest values.

However, when I run this code it not only drops the max value, but also its duplicate:

```
>>> [x for x in my_list if x!=max(my_list)]

Output: [10]
```

Everything works as expected when there are no duplicates in the list:

```
>>> my_list = [12,11,10]
>>> [x for x in my_list if x!=max(my_list)]
Output: [11, 10]
```

How can I keep the duplicate value?

Comment: Add BREAK after the IF condition evaluated true in the for loop. so is will remove only the first value the exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass maximum value in the list to `list.remove` method; it removes the first occurrence of the value passed.

```py
>>> my_list.remove(max(my_list))
>>> my_list
[11, 10]
```

**PS:** It's a mutable operation, so it changes the original list.

Above works only when there's repeated maximum, you can combine it with what you have done:

```py
if my_list.count(max(my_list)) == 1:
    my_list = [i for i in my_list if i!=max(my_list)]
else:
    my_list.remove(max(my_list))
```

Comment: @FishballNooodles, thanks for pointing out. I just posted the partial solution because OP was already able to get it right for non-duplicated maximum, anyways, I have updated the solution.